# Firestore Saving Data Erratic Results

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Running an angular 5 project with firestore realtime db (not old firebase db, the new one).

I have a very odd issue where I am saving data to Firestore, when i run with Chrome Debugging on the object I am saving is working as expected.

However when I run the same process without the Debug tools in Chrome open, it is only saving some of the properties on the object.

I am not changing my code in any way and i am running the same process with the same file.  The simple properties createdAt and updatedAt are saving but the array of objects the data object is not saving.  Except if i run code in debug mode then it all works.

Very confused.  Any ideas welcome.

**APP Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FirestoreService } from './firestore.service';


import * as xmlLoader from 'xml2js';
import { parseString } from 'xml2js';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  name = 'Angular 5';

  constructor(private fss: FirestoreService) {

  }

  resultSet = [];

  loadXmlFile(files: FileList) {

    Array.from(files).forEach(file => {
      const myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
      myReader.readAsText(file);

      const propertyString = this.removeExtFromFileName(file.name);

      this.extractKronosConfiguration(myReader, this.resultSet, propertyString);
    });

    this.emitKronosConfiguration(this.resultSet);

  }

  removeExtFromFileName(file): string {
    return file.slice(0, -4);
  }

  emitKronosConfiguration(resultSet) {
    this.fss.add('kronos', resultSet);
  }

  private extractKronosConfiguration(myReader, resultSet, propertyString) {

    myReader.onloadend = function (e) {

      xmlLoader.parseString(myReader.result, (err, response) => {
        resultSet[propertyString] = [];
        if (response.Kronos_WFC.Response !== undefined) {
          response.Kronos_WFC.Response.forEach(responseItem => {
            if (responseItem[propertyString] !== undefined) {
              responseItem[propertyString].forEach(item => {
                if (item.$ !== undefined) {
                  resultSet[propertyString].push(item.$);
                }
              });
            }


});
    }
  });
};
```

}
}

**FIRESTORE SERVICE**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
  AngularFirestoreDocument
} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

type CollectionPredicate<T> = string | AngularFirestoreCollection<T>;
type DocPredicate<T> = string | AngularFirestoreDocument<T>;

@Injectable()
export class FirestoreService {

  colRef: any;

  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore) {

  }

  col<T>(ref: CollectionPredicate<T>, queryFn?): AngularFirestoreCollection<T> {
    return typeof ref === 'string' ? this.afs.collection<T>(ref, queryFn) : ref;
  }

  add<T>(ref: CollectionPredicate<T>, data) {
    const timestamp = this.timestamp;
    return this.col(ref).add({
      ...data,
      updatedAt: timestamp,
      createdAt: timestamp
    });
  }

  get timestamp() {
    return firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is reading this in the future, I ended up getting to the bottom of the problem thanks to Orion on codementor.

Basically it was the age old problem of asynchronous programming.  Essentially when I was running in debug i was stopping the program to look at the code, so the asynchronous tasks were completing before moving to the next step.

When not running in debug mode some of the functions were running before a previous tasks was completed and hence the data was not getting saved.

Making the functions async with an await on certain steps ensured all steps dependent on a previous step were completed (as a Promise) made sure that data was saved everytime.